# Cake php contain parent deep

Tags: cakephp, join, parent

I need to "Contain" 2 parent tables.

Country hasMany Proponent and Proponent hasMany Project ( see image )

What is wrong in this contain:

```
$params["contain"] = array(
                'Proponent' => array(
                    'fields' => array('id', 'name'),
                    'Country' => array('fields'=>array('id','name')) 
                )
            );
```

[image]

The Country model don't comeback on result only Proponent, I suspect that is a limitation of cake to get parent of parent.

[image]

Models:

[image]

More debugs, if i start from Country to Project all its ok but reverting the country dont comeback:

```
debug(ClassRegistry::init("Country")->find('all', array(
                    'fields' => array("id", "name"),
                    'conditions' => array('Country.id' => 33),
                    'contain' => array(
                        'Proponent' => array(
                            'fields' => array("id", "name"),
                            'Project' => array('fields' => array('id', 'name')
                            )
                        )
                    )
                        )
        ));

        debug(ClassRegistry::init("Project")->find('all', array(
                    'fields' => array("id", "name"),
                    'contain' => array(
                        'Proponent' => array(
                            'fields' => array("id", "name"),
                            'Country' => array('fields' => array('id', 'name')
                            )
                        )
                    )
                        )
        ));
```

Obs:

- My query retrive projects with (contain) proponents and proponents country.
- The relations on models and databases is ok (check many times).

Any tip?

> **Confirmed , any contain to "Parent -> Parent" stop one first Parent, OMG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

Comment: "The relations on models and databases is ok" - Are they defined in both directions? As in, have you defined Projects belongsTo Proponent and Proponent belongsTo Country along with Country hasMany Proponent and Proponent hasMany Project?

Comment: Yes i will shot this now...wait!